# How do I get both my console.logs to output same value?

Tags: javascript, callback

This program outprints first `0` then `189`. I know that its due to javascripts executing this asynchronously. What would be the correct way to make both logs output `189`? Without getting into callback hell?

```
roaming = [];

connection.query("SELECT land FROM roaming", function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    } else {
        res.forEach(function(entry){
            roaming.push(entry.land);   
        });
        console.log(roaming.length);
    }
});
console.log(roaming.length);
```

Comment: You can't get them the same. `connection.query()` is an asynchronous function. Your second `console.log()` runs immediately, it can't wait for it to complete. That's why async functions have callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use async/await

```
async function asyncStuff() {  
  //async stuff  
}

await asyncStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can use "callback function". It means a function can be passed as a parameter.
Example:

```
function hello (val1, callback) { 
   console.log(val1);
   callback();
 }
function callback() {
 //do something.
}
```

So you can pass callback function like hello ('a', callback);

Comment: This seems like a workaround, i might be at fault here. But is this considerd the standard way of doing this? What if I have a function that needs value of two SQL calls. Then I will need to ad a callback in my callback?